# In Kepler's third law, why isn't k somehow proportional to the planet's mass?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, astrophysics

Given Kepler's third law:

$\frac{T^2}{D^3} = \frac{4\pi^2}{G(M+m)} = k$

I'd expect that, the larger a planet's mass (m), the smaller it's constant (k). However, that's not what I've seen in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_laws_of_planetary_motion#Third_law_of_Kepler):

[image: Modern data from Kepler's values]

Shouldn't Jupiter and Saturn have the smallest $R^3/T^2$ values? Why don't they?

Comment: Bear in mind that we only know G to 4 significant figures, and that the mass of Jupiter is around $0.00095 M_\odot$

Comment: @PM2Ring Still, the numbers in the third column above were not calculated from G, but Saturn should have a bigger value than Uranus. Does this mean that our knowledge of the first two columns is so inaccurate?

Comment: Kepler's laws are only accurate for ideal 2 body systems. In reality, we need to take into account the gravitational attractions between the planets. Neptune was discovered because we needed another planet to account for the orbit of Uranus. (And of course we also need relativity, but those effects are very small).

Answer (score 1):

You confused $\frac{T^2}{R^3}$ with $\frac{R^3}{T^2}$.

The table gives the values of $\frac{R^3}{T^2}$.
According to that [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_laws_of_planetary_motion#Third_law_of_Kepler) it is
$$\frac{R^3}{T^2} = \frac{G(M+m)}{4\pi^2}.$$
So you would expect the *biggest* values for Jupiter and Saturn
(having the biggest $m$).

And even then you would only expect a difference in the
fourth decimal digit, because (as @PM2ring commented)
for Jupiter we have $m = 0.00095 \cdot M$.

Comment: OK, thank you. Still, Saturn should have a bigger value than Uranus on the table above, and this depends on the precision of T and R, not of G. So, in the given table, which column is so inaccurate: semi-major axis (R) or period (T)?

Comment: @Rodrigo The $R$ and $T$ values are given with 6 or more decimal
digits. So it seems these are actually measured with this
precision. May be the differing values of $R^3/T^2$ are
an effect of the big planets disturbing the orbits of
the other planets. But I'm not an expert in celestial mechanics.